# give a simple xml example for this xsd schema file

Tags: xml, xsd

Hi can anyone give me a simple XML example based on this XSD file which can be validate? or explain what it exactly should be?
i'm beginner to XSD and don't understand whole of this document! but i want to have a example to generate a XML with php based on this file which can be validate! Thank you

this is the XSD file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
<xs:complexType name="station">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="driver">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="birth_date" type="xs:date" />
        <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="avatar" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="lvb_system">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="line" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="start_time_operation" type="xs:time" />
                        <xs:element name="end_time_operation" type="xs:time" />
                        <xs:element name="count_vehicles">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                              <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                              <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="map" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="start_station" type="station" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xs:element name="end_station" type="station" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xs:element name="intermediate_stations" type="station" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5" />
                        <xs:element name="vehicles_line" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10" >
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="capacity" type="xs:integer" />
                                    <xs:element name="driver" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type='driver' />
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Module E :D, good luck MR Alireza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The online tool here:

http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html

does a pretty good job at answering your question.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Kay! that was exactly the Answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html to generate xml from xsd. Using that service, your XSD results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Document created with online XML Editor http://xmlgrid.net 2013/10/23 8:33:18  -->
<lvb_system>
     <line null="test attribute">
           <code>test string</code>
           <type>test string</type>
           <start_time_operation>test string</start_time_operation>
           <end_time_operation>test string</end_time_operation>
           <count_vehicles>test string</count_vehicles>
           <map>test string</map>
           <start_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </start_station>
           <end_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </end_station>
           <intermediate_stations>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </intermediate_stations>
           <vehicles_line null="test attribute">
                 <name>test string</name>
                 <capacity>9</capacity>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
           </vehicles_line>
     </line>
     <line null="test attribute">
           <code>test string</code>
           <type>test string</type>
           <start_time_operation>test string</start_time_operation>
           <end_time_operation>test string</end_time_operation>
           <count_vehicles>test string</count_vehicles>
           <map>test string</map>
           <start_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </start_station>
           <end_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </end_station>
           <intermediate_stations>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </intermediate_stations>
           <vehicles_line null="test attribute">
                 <name>test string</name>
                 <capacity>9</capacity>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
           </vehicles_line>
     </line>
     <line null="test attribute">
           <code>test string</code>
           <type>test string</type>
           <start_time_operation>test string</start_time_operation>
           <end_time_operation>test string</end_time_operation>
           <count_vehicles>test string</count_vehicles>
           <map>test string</map>
           <start_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </start_station>
           <end_station>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </end_station>
           <intermediate_stations>
                 <name>test string</name>
           </intermediate_stations>
           <vehicles_line null="test attribute">
                 <name>test string</name>
                 <capacity>9</capacity>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
                 <driver>
                       <name>test string</name>
                       <birth_date>2011-01-15</birth_date>
                       <email>test string</email>
                       <phone>test string</phone>
                       <avatar>test string</avatar>
                 </driver>
           </vehicles_line>
     </line>
</lvb_system>
```

Comment: This document fails to validate against given schema.

Comment: Unlikely, it's pretty much a foregone conclusion that the document validates against the schema when using the xml library which xmlgrid.net used to build the document. Also, to simply say that it fails is rather vague. What specifically fails? And which library are you using to validate it?

Comment: 'xmllint --noout --schema example.xsd example.xml'

There are a lot of errors and final message that validation fails. Xmllint uses libxml2 library for parsing and validating xml's.